# right shifting o.length with zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I was looking at the polyfill function for `Array.includes` and I found the following lines of code:

```
// 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
var len = o.length >>> 0;

// 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
//    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
var n = fromIndex | 0;
```

What is happening here and why they did it like that?

Comment: maybe to avoid checking if length is undefined or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that both converts a value to 32 bit integer number for bitwise operation and uses

1. [zero filled right shift `>>>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) with zero as operand, so no bitshifting, but zero filling and if the value is `undefined`, the result is zero
2. [bitwise OR `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) with zero as operand, returns the original converted number or zero if the first operand is `undefined`.

After converting to 32 bit integer, the number is returned in 64 bit float, the format of Javascript's numbers.

The length of an array [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) correspond to a positve 32 bit integer number.

> The `length` property of an object which is an instance of type `Array sets or returns the number of elements in that array. The value is an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

```js
var o = {},
    fromIndex;        

console.log(o.length >>> 0);
console.log(fromIndex | 0);
```

But why the different approaches, for the same outcome, is not clear.